# find out which method is pegging my IIS 7 server?

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, sql

I have a pretty simple web service app running on my server but every once and awhile it pegs one of my cores to 25% constantly until I stop and re-start then it goes back down to between 1% ~7%.

I cannot reproduce this behavior locally - is there a way to see which method kicked off this pegging problem?

Basic setup is an ASP.NET MVC 2 website talking to a SQL Server 2008 DB using SubSonic 3.

Answer (score 0):

I have heard good things about this company's profiler:

http://www.eqatec.com/tools/profiler/

Apparently, some parts of it a free for commercial use. Personally, I use Intellitrace in Visual Studio 2010...you find more about it here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee336126.aspx